# Input data recieved from an email into a CSV/Excel/LibreOffic Calc file

Tags: excel, perl, email, csv

Having a bit of trouble with a script I am trying to create. Basically I would like it to send out a reminder email to send hours I worked that day, then I send a reply, the script will read the email for date start time and end time and then input this data into a CSV/Excel/LibreOffic calc file. A new line for each date. I have manage to sort out the email sending and reading part, then inputting the data into a variable for the next subroutine to read (the excel bit). But I am not sure on how to go about this part. I have seen many suggestions of using Text::CSV and other modules but i'm not certain on how to use them? also how would I go about making it append to the end of the document instead of just overwriting it?

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Why not make a google or cloud office sheet and link to it in the email?

Answer (score 0):

CSV is very easy to read and parse, and Text::CSV is very easy to use too.  What specific problems are you having with Text::CSV, and what have you tried?

If you want true Excel format, it looks like you'd need to read the existing contents with something like [Spreadsheet::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~dmow/Spreadsheet-XLSX-0.13-withoutworldwriteables/lib/Spreadsheet/XLSX.pm), write it back out using something like [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.76/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm), and append your data to it as you're back out the original data.

CSV is simpler, though, if you can live with it.  You could open the file in append mode, and just write to it.  To do so, build up your data into columns, and "combine" them (`$csv->combine (@columns)`), then create a string out of that (`$csv->string()`) that you can write to your original file.